# iphone coredata with two xcdatamodel

Tags: iphone, core-data, datamodel

I've been working with core data (successfully ;) , following some tutorials and kind of getting all, but now I have a question about some basic tutorial I found some time ago (the author is not responding so here we go!)
this is the [tutorial](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/180100_iphone-core-data-tutorial-part-1), and the code for it is [here](http://sites.google.com/site/iprogramiphones/bukisatutorials/coredatatutorialpart1)

in this tutorial, there are 2 xcdatamodels??, why?  what is the timeStamp on the Event does?? I checked it in sqlitemanager, and after creating some data, timestamp doesnt save anything,

- so was it a mistake to leave the Event entity? with its datamodel?
  or  is there something Im missing?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `CoreDataTutorialPart1.xcdatamodel` (the model file containing the `Event` entity) was auto-generated by the Core Data Xcode template and isn't actually used anywhere in the project.